# Why is my exit statement not working properly?

Tags: python

the goal is to move between rooms in this simplified version of a text base game. The code works exactly as planned except for if you try and input 'exit' directly after inputting 'instructions'. after inputting 'instructions' the first 'exit' get ran in the else invalid statement then the second 'exit' input exits the game as intended. If you continue at least one input after 'instructions' than exit works properly as well.

```
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }


def instruction():
    """Function to give instructions on how to play the game"""
    print('Welcome to Module 6 Milestone')
    print('Move commands are go North, go South, go East, go West')
    print('Typing exit will exit the game')
    print('Inputting instructions will remind you of the game instructions')
    print('Good luck may the odds be in your favor')


def invalid():
    """Function for if an invalid input is entered"""
    print('------------')
    print('Whoops invalid command, try again')
    print('------------')


def main():
    """Main function that runs the movement between rooms"""
    current_room = 'Great Hall'
    print('\nYou are starting in the', current_room)
    move = input('What will you do next?\n>').split()
    directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']  # directions in the dictionary
    while True:
        if len(move) < 2:  # for one word inputs
            if 'exit' in move:  # exit the game
                print('\nThanks for playing!')
                break
            elif 'instructions' in move:  # reprint instructions
                instruction()
                print('------------')
                print('\nYou are in the', current_room)
            else:
                invalid()
                print('You are still in the', current_room)
            move = input('\nWhat will you do next?\n>').split()  # next move input
        if len(move) == 2:  # 2 word inputs
            if move[1] in directions:  # checks if move is a valid direction
                if move[1] in rooms[current_room]:  # if move is a valid direction in current room
                    current_room = rooms[current_room][move[1]]  # changes current room if valid
                    print('------------')
                    print('You have found the', current_room)
                elif move[1] not in rooms[current_room]:  # if move in directions but not a valid move in current room
                    print('------------')
                    print('Oh no it seems to be a dead in')
                    print('You are still in the', current_room)
            else:  # not a valid move command
                invalid()
                print('You are still in the', current_room)
            move = input('What will you do next?\n>').split()  # next move input
        else:  # invalid move command
            invalid()
            print('You are still in the', current_room)
            move = input('What will you do next?\n>').split()


instruction()  # prints instructions function when game runs
print('------------')
if __name__ == '__main__':  # if code is not imported than main() will run
    main()
```

Comment: `if len(move) == 2:` --> `elif len(move) == 2:` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    if len(move) < 2:  # for one word inputs
        # handle the input in various ways
        move = input('\nWhat will you do next?\n>').split()  # next move input
    if len(move) == 2:  # 2 word inputs
```

When a single-word command is entered, it is handled in the first `if` block, and then a new move is entered.

The problem is that since the second block is an `if` and not an `elif`, it processes the new move immediately.

Generally it's better to ask for user input in only one place, near the top of the loop:

```
while True:
    move = input("...").split()
    if len(move) < 2:
        # handle it
    elif len(move) == 2:
        # handle it
    else:
        # handle it
```

Answer (score 1):

After your line

```
move = input('\nWhat will you do next?\n>').split()  # next move input
```

You should jump back to the beginning of the loop, using `continue`.